# Llamar a constructor plantilla en clase no-plantilla desde clase hija

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy haciendo un *wrapper* en C++ para una librería en C ([libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/api.html), por si hay curiosidad).

Para mantener el código lo mas *portable* posible, estoy usando *punteros* a las `struct` originales.

Cada tipo de `struct` cuenta con una función de inicialización propia; pero, en mi *wrapper*, parto de una clase base que encierra en una `union` todos los posibles tipo de punteros a usar.

Para inicializar esos punteros, tengo que realizar una llamada a una función C concreta; para ello, mi clase base **no es plantilla**, pero **cuenta con un constructor plantilla**; la idea es que, desde cada clase hija, se llame a la especialización concreta a usar en cada caso.

Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas para llamar al constructor-plantilla de la clase base:

```
struct uv_loop_t {
  void *data;
};

struct uv_tcp_t {
  void *data;
};

void uv_loop_init( uv_loop_t * );
void uv_tcp_init( uv_tcp_t * );

namespace uv {

class uvbase {
protected:
  static uv_loop_t *currentLoop;

  union {
    uv_loop_t *loop;
    uv_tcp_t *tcp;
  };

  template< typename T > uvbase( void * = nullptr );

public:
  uvbase( ) = delete;
};

class uvloop: public uvbase {
public:
  uvloop( void *d = nullptr ) : uvbase< ::uv_loop_t >( d ) { }
};

}

template< > uv::uvbase::uvbase< uv_loop_t >( void *d ) {
  loop = new uv_loop_t;
  uv_loop_init( loop );
  loop->data = d;
}

template< > uv::uvbase::uvbase< uv_tcp_t >( void *d ) {
  tcp = new uv_tcp_t;
  uv_tcp_init( tcp );
  tcp->data = d;
}
```

Para probar que está correcto, ejecuté

> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c test.hpp

Y obtuve una *bonita* secuencia de errores:

> test.hpp: In constructor ‘uv::uvloop::uvloop(void*)’:
>   test.hpp:31:33: error: ‘class uv::uvbase uv::uvbase::uvbase’ is not a non-static data member of ‘uv::uvloop’
>           uvloop( void *d = nullptr ) : uvbase< ::uv_loop_t >( d ) { }
>
> test.hpp:31:39: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
>      uvloop( void *d = nullptr ) : uvbase< ::uv_loop_t >( d ) { }
>
> test.hpp:31:39: error: use of deleted function ‘uv::uvbase::uvbase()’
>   test.hpp:26:3: note: declared here
>      uvbase( ) = delete;
>
> test.hpp:31:39: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
>      uvloop( void *d = nullptr ) : uvbase< ::uv_loop_t >( d ) { }

A continuación, cambié mi clase `uvloop` a

```
class uvloop: public uvbase {
public:
  uvloop( void *d = nullptr ) : uvbase::uvbase< ::uv_loop_t >( d ) { }
};
```

en un intento de indicar *explicitamente* que quiero llamar a un constructor plantilla.

Los resultados no mejoraron mucho:

> test.hpp: In constructor ‘uv::uvloop::uvloop(void*)’:
>   test.hpp:31:47: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
>      uvloop( void *d = nullptr ) : uvbase::uvbase< ::uv_loop_t >( d ) { }
>
> test.hpp:31:47: error: use of deleted function ‘uv::uvbase::uvbase()’
>   test.hpp:26:3: note: declared here
>      uvbase( ) = delete;
>
> test.hpp:31:47: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
>      uvloop( void *d = nullptr ) : uvbase::uvbase< ::uv_loop_t >( d ) { }

- ¿ Como llamo a una especialización concreta del constructor de la clase base desde el constructor de la clase hija ?

Comment: Gracias @PaperBirdMaster ¡ Eres un crack ! Espero a que publiques la respuesta :-)

Comment: yo recien aprendo C++ y no le veo proposito al `void *`, hasta donde se, ese puntero apunta a basura, y luego le asignas `nullptr` que es una implementacion de no apuntar a nada. Que raros estos codigos de los admin...

Comment: @RenatoA. Los `void *` tienen un uso muy claro. Si haces un `int *`, **solo** le puede asignar un puntero a `int`. Un `float *` **solo** admite un puntero a `float`. Un `void *` **admite un puntero a cualquier cosa**. Se usan mucho en `union` de varios punteros (para hacer *casting* automático), o en clases base cuyas hijas son clases plantilla, para minimizar la duplicación de código. Son **muy** útiles :-)

Comment: vaya no tenia idea de eso, creo q lo hubiese intuido si fuese `auto *` pero esa declaracion no es legal(creo). No tenia idea que los void tenian esa propiedad, gracias por la informacion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problema.

Es un problema curioso, reproducible con el siguiente código:

```
struct base { template <typename T> base() {} };
struct derivada : public base {};
```

Estamos indicando que la clase `base` tiene un constructor por defecto, que incluso definimos, no debería ser un problema crear una instancia `derivada` con constructor por defecto ya que llamaría al constructor por defecto de `base`.

Pero, el problema es que `base` tiene constructor por defecto (constructor sin parámetros) plantilla y como tal, no existe hasta que se instancia, como problema adicional el hecho de que tenga un constructor definido (aunque inexistente) hace que otros constructores no sean considerados así que el *verdadero* constructor por defecto se considera borrado, dado que la clase base no tiene constructor por defecto la derivada no puede construirse.

#### Solución.

Una solución que podríamos pensar es indicar el parámetro plantilla de la clase base en las clases derivadas:

```
struct base { template <typename T> base() {} };
struct derivadaint : public base<int> {};
struct derivadachar : public base<char> {};
```

Pero falla porque esa sintaxis le indica al compilador que la clase `base` es plantilla, cuando no es cierto, la plantilla es tan sólo el constructor no la clase entera.

Así pues, la única manera de desambiguar el constructor plantilla de la clase base es al instanciarlo, en ese momento se podrá deducir el tipo subyacente de la plantilla ¡pero al carecer de parámetros, el constructor e la clase base no tiene ningún tipo sobre el que hacer deducciones!.

Por lo tanto, sólo queda la alternativa de añadir un parámetro al constructor para que el tipo de la plantilla pueda deducirse:

```
struct base { template <typename T> base(const T &) {} };
// parametro auxiliar para forzar deuccion --> ^^^

struct derivadaint : public base { derivadaint() : base(int{}) {} };
//                   usa el constructor base de int --> ^^^^^
struct derivadachar : public base { derivadachar() : base(char{}) {} };
//                    usa el constructor base de char --> ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que no puedes especificar el argumento template en la llamada al constructor. Es que, literalmente, no tienes donde ponerlo; se debe confiar en la deducción automática del tipo.

Yo creo que debe haber algunas otras soluciones, incluida el uso de herencia, pero confiando en la deducción automática de tipos, una solución te propongo es:

```
struct uv_loop_t {
    void *data;
};

struct uv_tcp_t {
    void *data;
};

void uv_loop_init(uv_loop_t *) { }
void uv_tcp_init(uv_tcp_t *) { }

namespace uv {

    class uvbase {
    protected:
        static uv_loop_t *currentLoop;

        union {
            uv_loop_t *loop;
            uv_tcp_t *tcp;
        };

        template<typename T> uvbase(T *d = nullptr) { };
        template<> uvbase(uv_loop_t* d);
        template<> uvbase(uv_tcp_t* d);

    public:
        uvbase() = delete;
    };

    class uvloop : public uvbase {
    public:
        uvloop(uv_loop_t *d = nullptr) : uvbase(d) { }
    };

    class uvtcp : public uvbase {
    public:
        uvtcp(uv_tcp_t *d = nullptr) : uvbase(d) { }
    };
}



template<>
uv::uvbase::uvbase(uv_loop_t *d)
{
    loop = new uv_loop_t;
    uv_loop_init(loop);
    loop->data = d;
}

template<>
uv::uvbase::uvbase(uv_tcp_t *d)
{
    tcp = new uv_tcp_t;
    uv_tcp_init(tcp);
    tcp->data = d;
}
```

Comment: Te has adelantado a otro usuario, que me indicó la solución en el chat. +1 y, si no publica nada entre hoy y mañana, te la acepto. Que conste que dejé un comentario en la pregunta :-)

Comment: Que yo haya dado la solución en el chat no debería ser impedimento para que otras personas aporten soluciones también :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Cierto, y lo agradezco. Pero, ciertamente, la respuesta que **me sirvió** fue la tuya, aunque fuera en el *chat* :-)